# Pegar dados dos elementos e passar para Inputs do form sem submit

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

acredito que deve ser simples minha questão, mas não tenho conhecimento ainda.
Vamos lá:
Tenho essa tela ai
Ao clicar no botão Usar este passar os dados cod e nome para formulário, sem atualizar a página. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já fez alguma coisa? Precisa postar pelo menos uma ideia do seu código,